# Using an expression with multiple parameters in a linq statement

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, blazor

Ok so I am trying to write some Blazor code which will allow me to pass in an expression that is then used in a generic (template) class. Im not sure if my issue here is blazor related or just my lack of expression knowledge.

Here is my expression which lives in a separate file to the rest of the code. `u` (user) the entity to be searched, `s` (string) search text for the search.

```
private Expression<Func<User,string, bool>> SearchExpression => (u,s) => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)
         || ((u.Email.Contains(s)) || (u.UserName.Contains(s)));
```

Here is where I would like to use the expression.

```
private async Task GetItems()
{
    items = await context
        .Set<TItem>()
        .Where(q => SearchExpression)
        .Skip((currentPage - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize)
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

So the entity being searched is of type `TItem` (which in this case is a User), however I need to include the `searchText` but I cannot for the life of me work out how. Originally I had the expression with `searchText` as a parameter but I also dont know how to call it that way.

Comment: If `s` is empty there's no reason at all to add the `Where` clause. As for using one or more parameters - `Where (q=>SearchExpression(q,value))`.

Comment: s is not empty, I just haven't included it in my sample code because I cant find any way to do so that compiles. When I try to do it as you have suggested i get "Non-invocable member '...SearchExpression' cannot be used like a method"

Comment: Consider using Dynamic Linq - System.Linq.Dynamic.Core

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) here. It needs just configuring DbContextOptions:

```cs
builder
    .UseSqlServer(connectionString)
    .WithExpressionExpanding(); // enabling LINQKit extension
```

Then you can use your expression via `Invoke` extension:

```cs
private async Task GetItems()
{
    items = await context
        .Set<TItem>()
        .Where(q => SearchExpression.Invoke(q, str))
        .Skip((currentPage - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize)
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

Your `SearchExpression` will be injected into ExpressionTree and correct SQL should be generated.

Comment: I had tried linq kit before but was unaware of the need to add `.WithExpressionExpanding()` to the builder. Thank you very much

Comment: It is new. Latest version has this feature.