# linq extension method that uses a custom database routine

Tags: c#, linq

Im trying to create a linq extension method that uses a selector expression, and also uses a custom database routine that i wrote, I currently have something like this:

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<T> MyExtensionMethod<T>(
            this IQueryable<T> source, 
            Expression<Func<T, string>> selector,
            SortDirection sortDirection)
        {
            return sortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending
                ? source.OrderBy(x => DbRoutines.MyDbRoutine(selector.Compile()(x)))
                : source.OrderByDescending(x => DbRoutines.MyDbRoutine(selector.Compile()(x)));
        }
```

However this causes the linq error: 'the query <my query> could not be translated.'

I think the issue is that i need to compose the selector function inside of the dbroutines.mydbroutine function, however i dont know how i can do that in a way which is acceptable for linq

Comment: It would start work immediately if you activate [LINQKit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68899378/10646316), otherwise it is needed to manipulate with expression tree.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv thank you for your answer, i have linqkit already installed, however i did not have the builder.WithExpressionExpanding. The problem im having now is that the WithExpressionExpanding method doesnt seem to exist on the builder

Comment: Which EF Core version and which LINQKit package do you use?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv linqkit 1.1.27 and entity framework core 6.0.1

Comment: You have to use package `LinqKit.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 6` instead

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv i installed linqkit.microsoft.entityframeworkcore version 6.0.27 yet that doesnt seem to allow me to use that WithExpressionExpanding method either

Comment: `using LinqKit;` ?

Comment: Yes, i did do `use LinqKit;`

Comment: Replace then `selector.Compile()(x)` with `selector.Invoke(x)`

Comment: Both `selector.Compile()(x)` and `selector.Invoke(x)` cause the cannot translate error

Comment: Something wrong on your side. Well, have you tried `AsExpandable`?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv i dont have that method available on my iqueryable

Comment: I think i really need that WithExpressionExpanding method, but it just cant find it

Comment: I have created test project, everything is there. You have to apply it while building DbContextOptions.